# What is the meaning of pct_trend_adjusted in FiveThirtyEight's polling data?

Tags: dataset

I'm working on polling data from [fivethirtyeight](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2020-primary-data/pres_primary_avgs_2020.csv). What is the meaning of the **pct_trend_adjusted** column here? I understand that `pct` stands for percentage, but I don't get what the trend is that they are adjusting for, and how these figures are obtained.

Comment: This link is broken.

Comment: Please fix the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the methodology provided by FiveThirtyEight](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/what-makes-our-new-2020-democratic-primary-polling-averages-different/), it seems as though this figure (i.e. polling figures on state level) is adjusted for trends in national polls. See differentiator 1 on the linked page for more info:

> Basically, in states that haven’t been polled recently, we make
> inferences about what’s going on there using national polls or polls
> from other states that have been surveyed recently